# Avoid automatic restart of Service using StartCommandResult.Sticky/NonSticky

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, service

What I have going on is that I made a simple service in Xamarin.Android which for now simply just sends a single Local Push Notification.

In my main application (MainActivity) I have made a statement that checks whether or not this service runs. If it does not, I will simply start the service, otherwise I'll do nothing.

```
if (UtilityController.IsServiceRunning(typeof(WidgetService), this) == false)
{
    StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(WidgetService)));
}
```

This works fine aswell. No problems here.

Now, the issue is when it comes to my Service being ran multiple times.

```
[Service]
public class WidgetService : Service
{
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        SendPushNotification();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    //Other functions such as OnBind, OnDestroy etc..
}
```

Here I have a service that is straight forward. It's only purpose  is to send a Push Notification in the function `SendPushNotification();` which it does.

However, when I'm using different `StartCommandResult` enums, my `OnStartCommand` function gets triggered in different ways (which I assume is because it restarts the service):

- Using `StartCommandResult.Sticky` makes the Service restart itself every time I close/kill the main app.
- Using `StartCommandResult.NotSticky` makes the Service restart itself every time I start the main app.

This is a problem. I want the Service to only be run ONCE while it's still running. I don't want it ever to be restarted unless I specifically tells it to.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `Using StartCommandResult.NotSticky makes the Service restart itself every time I start the main app.` The Service is not going to start/restart itself unless told to, i.e. `StartService`

Comment: @SushiHangover Well apparently it does.

Comment: Then you are calling `StartService` in the start of your app,  Service Lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you have provided, what is happening should be something like this:

While using `StartCommandResult.Sticky`: As you have described, service is being restarted when you kill the service process. But this time `OnStartCommand` is being called with a null intent.

While using `StartCommandResult.NotSticky`: In this case, service is being stopped when you kill the process but notifications are not removed. When you start the app again, since service is not started, it will start a fresh from your activity.

What you could do depends on the behaviour you do expect from your app. If you want the service to stop when you close/kill the app, you can do something like this:

```
[Service]
public class WidgetService : Service
{
    bool isStarted;
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent 
    intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!isStarted)
        {
            SendPushNotification();
            isStarted = true;
        }
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    //Only will be called if stopWithTask attribute is set to false
    public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {

        // Remove the notification from the status bar.
        base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        // We need to shut things down.
        // Remove the notification from the status bar.
        isStarted = false;
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

And stop the service when you are done with it or app is being closed. But if you want to keep the service running, since you are displaying a notification, I would suggest to make your service a [foreground service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/)